# Is it a or an "identity verification concept"?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article, spelling

In this suggested edit on https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/80054 Security SE

> is a identity verification concept that claims [...]

to

> is an identity verification concept that claims [...]

Is this right?

I thought as it is refering to "concept" and not to "identity", it wouldn't be "an".
Have I been wrong?

Comment: @AlanCarmack: What you mean? SOrry not getting it(the first part of your comment).

Comment: The choice of *a* or *an* is determined by the word that immediately follows it, which is *identity*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Then make that aN answer. Wasn't aware of this. but what did you mean with concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of *a* or *an* is determined by the immediately following word, which is *identity*. So you would use *an*, since identity starts with a vowel sound. This is a spelling issue.

Which spelling to use is **not** determined by the head noun of the noun phrase. For example, the complete noun phrase is

> an identity verification concept that claims to verify a person by asking it about stuff just this person knows of, collected from "public information"

That noun phrase can be reduced to

> a concept

Even though this is true, you still spell the indefinite article according to which word comes immediately after it, whether it is the head noun (a concept) or a modifier (an identity...) of the head noun.

Comment: Again I don't understand the second part: How does this help solving this? Or did you just explain what I did and forget to add thats NOT what gets applyed here?

Comment: @Zabis What do you mean by: *I thought as it is refering to "concept" and not to "identity", it wouldn't be "an"*?

Comment: Exactly what you describe I meant by it. But you just give it a word, without stating why this doesn't or does (but in a diferent way) is related here. Thats what is confusing.